# iPhone:Open-gl to start with..?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am developing several iPhone applications using UIKit. I want to learn and develop a simple and rich graphics iPhone game application using Open-gl library quickly. I googled it and got some links like below.
http://maniacdev.com/2009/04/8-great-resources-for-learning-iphone-opengl-es/

But i want to hear from you experience people if you have any suggestions, please give me the link/any other resource where i can start with to create a simple and rich graphics game using open-gl for iPhone.

I appreciate your helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jeff LaMarche's [iPhone Development blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/) is great, and he has a perfect intro OpenGL ES series up here: [OpenGL ES From The Ground Up: Table of Contents](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) (I believe there is still new content being added as well).

More resources: [16 Killer iPhone OpenGL ES Resources](http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/16-killer-opengl-es-resources/)