# I want to create game using OpenGL ES for iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I want to use openGL ES for my games of IPhone3 and IPhone4 but i don't know where to start ,please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944403/iphoneopen-gl-to-start-with  and many more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please go through this book-

http://iphone-3d-programming.labs.oreilly.com/ch01.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look to these tutorials:

http://www.71squared.com/iphone-tutorials/